# Concavity of a function with a singular discontinuity in the 2nd derivative

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose I have a function $f(x):[a,c]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as 
$f(x)=\cases{f_1(x),\ a\leq x\leq b\\f_2(x),\ b<x\leq c}$ where $f_1(x),f_2(x)$ are two concave functions over the domains $[a,b],\ [b,c]$ respectively. Given that $f_1(b)=f_2(b)$ and that $f_1'(b)=f_2'(b)$ (where the derivatives at $b$ are naturally left for $f_1$ and right for $f_2$), how do I prove that $f(x)$ is concave? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a straightforward proof if $f_k$ are differentiable:

A differentiable $f$ is concave **iff** $f'$ is non increasing.

Since both $f_k'$ are non increasing, and $f'_1(b) = f'_2(b)$, we see that
$f'$ is non increasing, hence concave.

This can be generalised in a number of ways, but the proofs a little messier.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the lemma that says that
> A differentiable $f$ is concave iff $f′$ is non increasing.
do you have a reference that proves it?

Comment: I don't have access to my library at the moment, but you could look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties, Properties #1 & #4.

Comment: @copper.hat It doesn't need to be that "both $f_k$ are non increasing", does it? Do you mean to say Since both $f_k'$ are non increasing?

Comment: @user106860: Yup, thanks. Typo.